# VB.Net Public Variable Resetting For Unknown Reason

Tags: vb.net, timer, public

I am working on a Windows Forms App in VS19. I have a login form which accesses user info on a mysql database, including whether or not they want an autosave feature turned on. The user edits orders through the Order Form. From the Order Form the user can toggle the AutoSave Feature, stored as a boolean on the Login Form(which is hidden after login). The autosave runs a timer, which checks to see if AutoSave is turned on before scheduling the next save event. For some reason, after saving once, the AutoSave boolean seems to be resetting to false. I cannot figure out why. I have not completed the save code yet. So far I am struggling to get the autosave to fire properly.

```
'Login Form Code
    Public autosave As Boolean


'Order Form Code
    
     Sub schedulenextautosave()
        If frmLogin.autosave = True Then
            Dim t As New System.Timers.Timer(5000)
            AddHandler t.Elapsed, New ElapsedEventHandler(AddressOf autosave)
            t.AutoReset = False
            Debug.Print(frmLogin.autosave)
            t.Start()
        End If

    End Sub

    Sub autosave()
        'run saving stuff
        MsgBox("Saved")
        Debug.Print(frmLogin.autosave)
        If frmLogin.autosave = True Then Call schedulenextautosave()

    End Sub

    Private Sub mtsbAutoSave_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles mtsbAutoSave.Click 
        If frmLogin.autosave = True Then
            frmLogin.autosave = False
            mtsbAutoSave.Checked = False
        Else
            frmLogin.autosave = True
            mtsbAutoSave.Checked = True
            schedulenextautosave()
        End If
    End Sub

'''
```

Comment: You shouldn't have a public field in the first place. If you were using a property, as you should be, then you could put a breakpoint on the setter and you'd be able to see exactly when and where from the value gets changed. Fortunately for you, you can change it to a property without affecting any code that currently uses it. Do that.

Comment: Having said that, it's quite possibly not getting set at all. You are using the defa8ult instance of `frmLogin` to get the `autosave` value but that will not be the same instance that you displayed if that instance gets disposed. You shouldn't be using that field that way in the first place. When the user sets that value in the form, you should be saving it somewhere else outside the form that it can be accessed from anywhere in the project. Forms are not to be used for data storage like that.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Your first solution didn't seem to do anything. The value changed without calling the setter somehow. But then I moved it to my connection module and everything seems to work fine now.

Comment: It's not possible for the value of a property to change without the setter being executed unless you were setting the backing field directly, which would not be possible with an auto-property or even a fully-implemented property with a private backing field. The issue would have been what I said in my second comment. It was not that the value was changing but that you were using a different form in which the field/property had never been set to `True` in the first place.